# Rest Controller and API Rate Limits or how to set CSRF token invalid

Tags: json, security, api

Problem: 
I have a JSON endpoint and like to limit access to it. 
I.e. to prevent double submits on contact forms or brute force attempts.

One solution that came to my mind was rate-limiting the requests, but I did not find a Craft way to archive this with my controllers.

Another idea was to set the CSRF token to invalid after X requests. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not a real answer, but there's is a guide on how to do it in Yii (which is the framework Craft uses) here that might be helpful: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-rate-limiting

Comment: I was aware of the option, since craft has their very own implementation of the user model, i do not see any chance to use the behavior of yii. (please correct me if am wrong)